# Success with start-stop-daemon and mono-service2?

Tags: mono, daemon, init, mono-service

Has anyone had any success using start-stop-daemon and mono-service2 together?  I've been fighting this for a few days now and have gotten various bits to work, but have had no success in getting a fully functional init script for a mono service.

Here is what I have learned to date:

1. The mono or mono-service exe must be named as the variable DAEMON (you can't list your exe as the DAEMON)
2. You must use the --background flag ... otherwise when this script is executed from a package installer (deb in my case). The service terminiates when the installer ends (has something to do with how the installer forks processes ... I havent investigated this much).
3. I have had success with listing the pid file with the mono-service flag in other scripts and using it to stop the daemon, but for some reason it doesnt work here.  As such the script below does not stop the service - not sure why.  Start works fine.

And here is my partially functional init script:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          ServiceName
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Starts and Stops Service
# Description:       Service start|stop|restart
### END INIT INFO

# Author: Author
#

# Do NOT "set -e"

# PATH should only include /usr/* if it runs after the mountnfs.sh script
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Description of the service"
NAME=Service.exe
DAEMONNAME=ServiceDaemon.sh
INSTALLDIR=/usr/sbin/
DAEMON=/usr/bin/mono-service2
EXENAME=Service.exe
PIDFILE=/var/run/$DAEMONNAME.pid
DAEMON_ARGS=" -l:$PIDFILE $INSTALLDIR/$EXENAME"
#DAEMON_ARGS=" $INSTALLDIR/$EXENAME"
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$DAEMONNAME

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6) to ensure that this file is present.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
 # Return
 #   0 if daemon has been started
 #   1 if daemon was already running
 #   2 if daemon could not be started
 start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
  || return 1
 start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --exec $DAEMON -- \
  $DAEMON_ARGS \
  || return 2
 # Add code here, if necessary, that waits for the process to be ready
 # to handle requests from services started subsequently which depend
 # on this one.  As a last resort, sleep for some time.
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
 # Return
 #   0 if daemon has been stopped
 #   1 if daemon was already stopped
 #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
 #   other if a failure occurred
 start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --name $NAME
 RETVAL="$?"
 [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
 # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks
 # and if the daemon is only ever run from this initscript.
 # If the above conditions are not satisfied then add some other code
 # that waits for the process to drop all resources that could be
 # needed by services started subsequently.  A last resort is to
 # sleep for some time.
 start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry=0/30/KILL/5 --exec $DAEMON
 [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2
 # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
 rm -f $PIDFILE
 return "$RETVAL"
}

#
# Function that sends a SIGHUP to the daemon/service
#
do_reload() {
 #
 # If the daemon can reload its configuration without
 # restarting (for example, when it is sent a SIGHUP),
 # then implement that here.
 #
 start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 1 --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
 return 0
}

case "$1" in
  start)
 [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
 do_start
 case "$?" in
  0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
  2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
 esac
 ;;
  stop)
 [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
 do_stop
 case "$?" in
  0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
  2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
 esac
 ;;
  status)
       status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
       ;;
  #reload|force-reload)
 #
 # If do_reload() is not implemented then leave this commented out
 # and leave 'force-reload' as an alias for 'restart'.
 #
 #log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC" "$NAME"
 #do_reload
 #log_end_msg $?
 #;;
  restart|force-reload)
 #
 # If the "reload" option is implemented then remove the
 # 'force-reload' alias
 #
 log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
 do_stop
 case "$?" in
   0|1)
  do_start
  case "$?" in
   0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
   1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
   *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
  esac
  ;;
   *)
    # Failed to stop
  log_end_msg 1
  ;;
 esac
 ;;
  *)
 #echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload}" >&2
 echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart|force-reload}" >&2
 exit 3
 ;;
esac

:
```

Answer (score 12):

We had a lot of issues with mono-service and ended up implementing our own "service" code in our app. Nothing hard, just grabbing some signals:

```
UnixSignal intr = new UnixSignal (Signum.SIGINT);
UnixSignal term = new UnixSignal (Signum.SIGTERM);
UnixSignal hup = new UnixSignal (Signum.SIGHUP);
UnixSignal usr2 = new UnixSignal (Signum.SIGUSR2);

UnixSignal[] signals = new UnixSignal[] { intr, term, hup, usr2 };

for (bool running = true; running; )
{
    int idx = UnixSignal.WaitAny(signals);

    if (idx < 0 || idx >= signals.Length) continue;

    log.Debug("daemon: received signal " + signals[idx].Signum.ToString());

    if ((intr.IsSet || term.IsSet)) 
    {
        intr.Reset ();
        term.Reset ();

        log.Debug("daemon: stopping...");

        running = false;
    }
    else if (hup.IsSet)
    {
        // Ignore. Could be used to reload configuration.
        hup.Reset();
    }
    else if (usr2.IsSet)
    {
        usr2.Reset();
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old but there are no accepted answers.  I tinkered around with this for awhile too and came up with a daemon script which worked like a charm for me.  I blogged about it here: http://www.geekytidbits.com/start-stop-daemon-with-mono-service2/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Answer (score 1):

I got this script working with a couple of minor changes:

- A pidfile in /var/run only works if you run as root - if you try to run the script without sudo, mono-service will fail silently.
- Use --pidfile instead of --name to find the service to stop.

Answer (score 1):

```
do_stop()
{ 

test -f $PIDFILE && kill `cat $PIDFILE` && return 2

 start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --verbose --oknodo --retry=0/30/KILL/5\ 

--exec mono-service2

 [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2

 # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.

 rm -f $PIDFILE

 return "$RETVAL"

}
```

So it works, I think it just because you can't stop a process by the command "start-stop-daemon"
i'm learning to use mono now,your invitation help me very much.thank you.
my english is poor,forgive my half-baked english.